# Is $u(t)=u(2t)$ true?

Tags: derivatives, dirac-delta, step-function

Since $u(t)=1$ for $t>0$ and $0$ otherwise, this means that $u(t)=u(2t)$ for all $t$. Also, they both have identical graphs.

But when obtaining the derivative of both of these functions they give different results.
$$\frac{du(t)}{dt} = \delta(t)$$
$$\frac{du(2t)}{dt} = 2\delta(2t)$$
Where the second derivative is obtained using the chain rule.

So does this mean that $u(t)\neq u(2t)$? or the second derivative is wrong?

Comment: What is $u(t)$?

Comment: Is the function even derivable?

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi no, it's not even continuous

Comment: Well, $2\cdot0=0$

Comment: @QC_QAOA u(t) is the unit step function.

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi I am not sure in terms of very detailed math but in general, I know that the relation $\frac{du(t)}{dt}=\delta(t)$ is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*
We want derivative in the sense of distributions.  So to check equality, you need to check equality in the sense of distributions.  What distribution is $2 \delta(2t)$?  That is, if $\varphi$ is a test function, what is $\langle 2\delta(2t), \varphi\rangle$? Is that the same distribution as $\delta(t)$?  Answer: Yes.

> But: if you do not know how to compute in distributions, then this question is too advanced for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know much about distributions so this next part may be invalid.
Isn't $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta(t)dt=1$ and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty2\delta(2t)dt=2$? Can they be the same distribution and have these different integral values?

Comment: No, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty2\delta(2t)dt=1$.  If you think "change of variables" $s = 2t$ makes sense, try it.